# What is wrong with tuning parameters on training set as opposed to validation set?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, validation

When creating a machine learning model it is suggested to split your data into train, validation, and test sets. Here is my understanding of what they are for.

- Train: Use this to train the different models that you want to use.
- Validation: Use this to tune each of these models, such as the
  regularization parameter
- Test: Use this to compare the final models and select which one is
  best based on some type of error analysis.

  ---

**An example in a machine learning course I am taking is**

1. Train the models of interest: 
   $$\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 $$
   $$\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 $$
   $$\hat{y} = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_3$$
2. Adjust $\beta$ 's for each model using parameter regularization with the validation data.
3. Then test each of these models against the test data where you can then select the most optimal one.

   ---

I understand why you do not want to use the test data when tuning the model using regularization because then you are essentially fitting to the test data set.

> However, I am wondering what can go wrong when tuning parameter on the
>   training dataset instead of the validation data set? It is not immediately clear to me what issues can arise.

Comment: If you were to tune using only the training set, you would select the tuning parameter that fits best in-sample and thus would overfit the most. By using a validation set, you can assess overfitting vs. underfitting and select the parameter that is the sweet spot in the middle.

Comment: Take e.g. k-nearest neighbour. If you optimize k insample, the "optimal" k will be 1.